# Linear Independence of Power Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

Let $p_{1},p_{2},\cdots,p_{K}$ be a non-uniform probability distribution (i.e., not all $p_{k}$s are the same) with $K$ being a fixed positive integer. Consider the following $K\times K$ matrix.
$$
  A=\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
           1&1&\cdots& 1 \\
           p_{1}&p_{2}&\cdots & p_{K} \\
           p_{1}^2&p_{2}^2&\cdots &p_{K}^2 \\
            \vdots& \vdots &  \vdots & \vdots \\
           p_{1}^{K-1}&p_{2}^{-1}K&\cdots &p_{K}^{K-1} 
         \end{array}
 \right)
$$
Can $\det(A)$ be zero, in other words, can the the column vectors (or row vectors) of $A$ be linearly dependent?

Comment: Choose $p_1  = p_2 = 0$.

Comment: Then what happens?

Comment: Two identical columns hence singular.

Comment: Hmm, true. Trivial - bad question! Thanks.

Comment: This is a Vandermonde matrix. It's non-singular iff all the $p_i$ are distinct.

Comment: Just curious, what has this got to do with differential geometry?

Comment: @copper.hat, perhaps nothing. In a weak and muddy mathematical mind, taxonomy of mathematics could be a real issue. lol

Comment: @StudentofStatistics: My mind is equally muddy.